# Do AD GPO's affect workstations if nobody is logged in?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I have a few computers on the domain that misbehave.  (don't appear to follow GPO despite RSOP readout)

One issue in particular is a computer that seems to hang/sleep/comatose when nobody is logged into it over night.  If a user is logged in, it's fine. Domain GPO says no sleep.

[image]
So the symptoms beg the question, "When the computer is idle with no users, are the GPO's essentially deactivated because nobody is logged into the domain?"

Note:  I have enabled the setting "Turn off local group policy object processing"

Comment: What about "Specify a system sleep timeout" and "Specify the unattended sleep timeout" ... set them both to zero for never. You can also configure "Turn off the display" option if needed.

Comment: I had it backwards, the "0" is not defined, and I thought it would function the opposite way.  Thanks !

Comment: alas, this box still hung overnight despite the updated gpo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer Configuration settings in GPO's are applied to computers, so yes those settings are applied and effective whether a user is logged on or not.

Comment: That seems straight-forward.  I guess I could have seen the computer "log into domain" at boot from the DC.